# Unexpected compiler error at const member function

Tags: c++, object, reference, constants

I have some problems understanding the meaning of const in the context of objects/member functions.

See for example this code:

```
class Test
{
public:
  Test():a(0), b(new int){}
  int& get_a() const {return a;}
  int* get_b() const {*b = 5; return b;}

private:
  int a;
  int *b;
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  t.get_a();
  t.get_b();
  return 0;
}
```

I thought the const at the end of the function's signature means: This function does not change the object's state.

So I was expecting one Error at int* get_b() since it changes the object. The compiler however complains about this:

```
error: binding 'const int' to reference of type 'int&' discards qualifiers
int& get_a() const {return a;}
```

So why do I get an error for not changing anything, get_a() only returns a after all, no changes to the object in the function body of get_a.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Returning a non const ref to a member of a const qualified object violates its constness. It would all you to do foo.get_a() = 2; when you couldnt do foo.a = 2;. Also remember that const in C++ means bitwise const.

Comment: simply: `const int& get_a() const {return a;}`